# qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4090

Tags: qemu

guys

```
sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsn32-static bin/boa
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4090
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4090
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4004
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4001
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

Got this 'boa' from a firmware which is running on a router within RTL8196D chip.

What should I do to make this work?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

System call number 4090 is mips_mmap and its not always implemented.
change it to mmap instead